# Enable Node.js coding assistance WebStorm doesn't work

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a big issue with WebStorm (I'm using WebStorm 2019.1.2 ultimate edition) where I tried to start coding Node.js using it, when I tried to write `require('fs');` it shows me an error message:

> unresolved function or method require()

and as a solution it suggested me to "Enable Node.js code assistance".

I've tried to enable it (directly from the suggestion than from going to Settings) but IT CAN'T BE ENABLED.

[image: click here to see the image]

I checked of course previous similar problems posted here on StackOverflow but I only found one post where the problem was the old version of WS (but I have 2019.1.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WEB-43088](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43088) is fixed in 2019.3.2. Please either upgrade WebStorm to the most recent version (2019.3.3) or downgrade Node.js

Comment: Yeaaah , it worked. Thank you so much for your help . I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I was using global packages. But when I installed packages locally in the project, it worked.